# What does this error about a missing system 32 file mean?

Tags: windows

[image]

> Windows Script Host
>
> Error: Cannot find script file
>
> "C:\Windows\system32\Maintenance.vbs"

When I'm on my laptop, this error occurs every time I plug in the charger. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: The only direct match for that file path on Google is a [Tom's Hardware post](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/cant-find-c-windows-system32-maintenance-vbs.3566186/) where the solution is to run an antivirus scan. The post claims Windows should not have a `.vbs` file there. The post claims it's malware.

Answer (score 1):

I would run `SFC /scannow` in command prompt as an administrator.
This will verify that all key windows files are installed and working properly. `.vbs` scripts tent too be malicious however so if this doesn't find any problems with windows I would run and antivirus scan